# QGIS Overlapping polygons transfer attributes

Tags: qgis

The image below is of vineyard blocks on different soil types (4 larger polygons - all different layers).
[image]

I would like to create a new attribute in the vineyard layer called soil type and fill it with the value from the 4 different soil type layer's attribute called description. In the case where the soil types overlaps the vineyard blocks the attribute soil type should be where more than 50% of the block lies within the soil type. 
I have looked, but cannot find a answer.I have tried  geomwithin( 'Alluvial' , 'Description') - a function I get in the field calculator after I installed the plugin refFunctions. However this only works, of course, if the vineyard polygon is completely within the soil type. I have played around with Union, but cannot see how that will help me.

Can someone please help me? I would prefer a expression, as I have no knowledge of scripting.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Regards

Comment: I think this question is better asked on: https://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you Wilmar, I try there.